# URL exists gives "Does not Exists"

Tags: php

To check if url exists not regular file

```
Tried
1. file_exists - just a test, should not be for a url
2. empty
3. fopen
```

All the above gave a "**Does not exists**

```
if(fopen("http://www.google.com",r)){ echo "exists"; } else { echo "doesnot exist"; }
```

I have ran out of ideas as to why its happening.  the file has been given 777.  Code is being tested from 127.0.0.1.

This is the only code on the page.  I do not wish to use curl, and keep it simple and normal coding.  Checked on Google and other Q's on stackoverflow

All I want to check is if the URL is real.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable allow_url_fopen in your php.ini config file.

Comment: Yes.. its the allow_url..thanks..have to wait 5 mins to approve.

Comment: I'm glad that solved the problem for you! The only reason I thought of that was that I had the same problem about a week ago.

Comment: At times its the simplest of the problems that brings the biggest of headaches

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini file and ensure you have access to the `fopen` function.

Also, the the first two parameters in `fopen` are strings. So the correct syntax of your command is:

```
if( fopen( "http://www.google.com", "r" ) !== false )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the php setting `allow_url_fopen` is set to false so this won't work. Did you try using CURL and checking the response headers?

Answer (score 1):

I ran this at my local machine

```
if (fopen("http://www.google.nl", 'r')) {
    echo 'exists';
} else {
    echo 'no exists';
}
```

While you do have an error (r doesnt exist, but is interperted as 'r', unless you defined it elsewhere this shoudn't be a problem.

Check your local php configuration and or system configuration. (possible the ini setting allow_url_fopen)